# How to get users location and show it in a container with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, location, geofence

I'm trying to develop a flutter app. The idea of the app is to get the location of some users and show it in a container (not in a map).

However, here we have some conditions, for example, my location is the main location of the list of locations and the most important, I can get the distance of the different locations, but I don't know how to show that position and that relations in my device without a map.

I know that with "position library" I can put any element where I want, so, I can tell to Flutter that if my location is the main location, to show a container (positioned a container) in the middle of the screen trying to simulate that I am that container for example. However, if I have another location on the left (around 10 meters of the left of the main location) how I can show it in my device?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this tutorial on medium can help you. you get user's longitude and latitude+adress:
https://medium.com/@fernnandoptr/how-to-get-users-current-location-address-in-flutter-geolocator-geocoding-be563ad6f66a

I have understood that you don't want to show the informations in a map, so I think this tutorial  can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however that article is not useful for my idea. I mean, I already know how to show the information for location.  I want to mark  the user location without any map

Comment: Hi, I don't really understand your question: You want to show a text ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to do something like a radar, my location (is the main  location) should be in the middle of the screen (marked with a white container for example ) and the other locations near the main one

Answer (score 0):

use this pulugin

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator,

there is a function that helps you listen current user location

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

final LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
  accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high,
  distanceFilter: 100,
);
StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings).listen(
    (Position? position) {
        print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : '${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}');
    });
```

Using a stateful class you can show this live location in container or any other widget.

Comment: Thanks, is pretty useful for me. However, my real problem is that I don't know how to mark that location in a container.

Comment: how you want to mark the location, you want to show in text or something else ?

Comment: like a circular, white  container for example